# .htaccess redirect www to non-www url doesn't not apply on the other link than the index

Tags: macos, .htaccess

I've a Mac server and everything working fine

I'm running a wordpress and have .htaccess to rewrite the rule for custom link and so on

right now I'm having a trouble once I visit my site

`http://www.mysite.com/anypage.html` This doesn't work and give me page not found error

but if I visit same page but removed the www `http://mysite.com/anypage.html` this will work fine

So I thought I will make sure if this happen to all the pages and it was having the problem with all the pages except the home page so if I visit `http://www.mysite.com` or `http://mysite.com` neither one will work

I tried with many .htaccess rewrite rules and non of them word

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please suggest what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the current rules that you have - remove the `www` from the host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `www` will be redirected to now www URLs.

Just do this and try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mysite\.com)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L]
```